Excel VBA asking user to select worksheet
Main objective is to select a Sheet from my workbook, example I have Sheet 1 to 10, the user will be requested to select only 1 sheet. Below is a sample of a code that I found whereby it will open a box to let user select a worksheet cell instead of a worksheet. I am not sure how I can add photos to show, but I will try my best to explain. Example a box appears, I must type in =Sheet1!$E$4 for it to work instead of just typing in =Sheet1. Any help is appreciated.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a worksheet", Title:="Select Worksheet", Type:=8).Parent
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "User cancelled...", vbInformation
    Else


If I understand correctly, you want the user to be able to manually type range address. Type:=8' specifies the input type as Range, you need to change it to Type:=2' which specifies the input type as String

If you just want to input any string then could use Inputbox() function or Application.Inputbox() like Application.InputBox("Type your sheet range").

You might consider using RefEdit control on a userform.

Input sheet name as String and check if it is a valid object.
    ws2_name = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a worksheet", Title:="Select Worksheet")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(ws2_name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsEmpty(ws2) Then
        MsgBox "User cancelled (or name error)...", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'here is code process
    ws2.Select


Mod on the comment
sh_list = "Select a sheet:"
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    sh_list = sh_list & Chr(10) & Worksheets(i).Name
Next i
    ws2_name = Application.InputBox(prompt:=sh_list, Title:="Select Worksheet")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(ws2_name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsEmpty(ws2) Then
        MsgBox "User cancelled (or name error)...", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ws2.Select

This will list the available sheet names in the input box.
A more refined workaround can be a ListBox in a Userform.

Thanks for the help @Black cat, this kind of helps. Do you know how I can list down all the sheets I have in the workbook and let user select the Sheet? Then I can assign the select sheet to ws2. Thank you.

You could include the i index in the sh_list and the user just has to input the index number?

@user23357972 What is your choice among these two worst solutions where the user should type the worksheet name manually?

The following works but needs proper error checking.  This should give you an option for doing what you have asked to do:
Dim InputStr As String

InputStr = Application.InputBox("Enter Name of Worksheet to Go To", "Go To Worksheet")

Worksheets(InputStr).Activate


To get the best result, you need to create a UserForm with the ComboBox control and fill it with worksheet names:

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name
Next


Reference a Worksheet Using User Input

The following should cover most of the various 'surprises' (protection and visibility are not covered) you may encounter.
It's up to you to decide what applies in your particular case.

Sub Test()
    
    ' Previously referenced (set) objects.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Define constants (usually on the top of the code).
    Const WORKSHEET_SELECTION_TITLE As String = "Worksheet Selection"
    
    ' Let the user enter the worksheet name.
    ' Use a Variant variable to distinguish between 'False' and "False".
    Dim InputValue As Variant: InputValue = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Please enter a worksheet name:", _
        Title:="WORKSHEET_SELECTION_TITLE", Type:=2) ' 2 means string
        
    ' Exit if the user cancelled the input box.
    If VarType(InputValue) = vbBoolean Then
    ' 'If InputValue = False Then' will not allow a sheet named "False".
        MsgBox "User cancelled!", vbExclamation, WORKSHEET_SELECTION_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Store the entered sheet name in a String variable.
    Dim Sheet2Name As String: Sheet2Name = InputValue
    
    ' Attempt to reference the sheet.
    ' Use an Object variable because it may not be a worksheet but a chart.
    Dim sh2 As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sh2 = wb.Sheets(Sheet2Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Exit if the sheet doesn't exist.
    If sh2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no sheet named """ & Sheet2Name & """ in workbook """ _
            & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation, WORKSHEET_SELECTION_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Exit if the sheet is not a worksheet.
    If Not TypeOf sh2 Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "Sheet """ & Sheet2Name & """ is not a worksheet!", _
            vbExclamation, WORKSHEET_SELECTION_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the 2nd worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = sh2
    Set sh2 = Nothing

    ' Exit if the 'chosen' 2nd worksheet is the same as the first worksheet.
    If ws2 Is ws1 Then
        MsgBox "The first sheet is named """ & ws1.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation, WORKSHEET_SELECTION_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
     
    ' Continue with the code using
    ' the 'wb', 'ws1', 'ws2' and 'Sheet2Name' variables.
    
    MsgBox "Created a reference to worksheet """ & ws2.Name & """ (""" _
        & Sheet2Name & """) in workbook """ & wb.Name & """!", _
        vbExclamation, WORKSHEET_SELECTION_TITLE

End Sub


You are in 1 step from getting the worksheet object in ws2
You need to change the single word only:
Sub asda()
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet, wsname As String
  On Error Resume Next
  Set ws2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a worksheet", _ 
    Title:="Select Worksheet", Type:=8).Worksheet ' here!
  On Error GoTo 0
  If ws2 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "User cancelled...", vbInformation
  Else
    wsname = ws2.Name
    MsgBox wsname
  End If
End Sub

The user should not enter the reference manually, it's possible to select a cell.
Prompt the user to select any cell on the target worksheet: Prompt:="Select any cell on the worksheet needed"

